# python path import collision

Tags: python-2.7, python-import

I have a Python application that has the following directory structure:

```
/home/vagrant/app
/home/vagrant/app/support
/home/vagrant/app/utils         (1)
/home/vagrant/app/examples/example_a
/home/vagrant/app/examples/utils        (2)
```

I've added /home/vagrant/app to my PYTHONPATH and all folders have `__init__.py` files.

I try to run the app by calling `/home/vagrant/app$ python ./example/example_a/ex_a.py`

It exits with a traceback:

```
File "./examples/example_a/ex_a.py", line 14, in <module>           (3)
   from support.sp1.py import *
File "/home/vagrant/app/support/sp1.py", line 11, in <module>       (4)
  from utils.mod_a import *
ImportError: No module named mod_a
```

A module named mod_a.py is present in `~/app/utils` but not `~/app/examples/utils`.

I have tried to rename `~/app/examples/utils` to `~/app/examples/utils-ex`. This resolves this issue but other things that rely on '/home/vagrant/app/examples/utils' are broken.

Is there a way to make the python interpreter look for utils (1) and not utils (2)? File (3) has a relative path (prefixed with dot) and file (4) has an absolute path ( prefixed with /). My thinking is that something is wrong with my setup, that makes the interpreter look in the app/examples folder before the app/. My launch path is in the app/examples/example_a path but the sp1.py isn't.

Of course, it would be simplest not to have utils and examples/utils, but this isn't my code and I'm loathe to rewrite it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up and accepted the inevitable Bash based solution:

```
cp -r ./examples/utils/ ./examples/xutils/
rm -R ./examples/utils/utils
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/examples.utils/examples.xutils/g'  {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable [absolute imports](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) first.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from utils.mod_a import foo, bar
```

Comment: I like the idea but that unfortunately didn't work - because the code depended on relative paths in ex_a.py. What I needed was relative in ex_a.py and absolute in sp1.py.